# Android - hebrew text displays incorrectly

Tags: android, locale, hebrew

So, I have some `TextView` with hebrew text in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="hebrew_example">מדביקים את המדבקה המצורפת
על גבו של החיישן</string>
```

and the `TextView`:

```xml
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hebrew_example"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Button" />
```

Phone has RTL enabled. All other hebrew texts show up fine. Could it be related with constraints that TextView has?

Comment: As a non-Hebrew speaker: what is the expected output?